# How do I select the first and last child of a parent element?

Tags: css

How do I select the first and last child of this. So the `<ul>` and last `<p>` are selected?

```
<blockquote>
  <ul></ul>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</blockquote>
```

I thought this would work:

```
blockquote:first-child {...}
blockquote:last-child {...}
```

but that just selects the `blockquote` element? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the descendant combinator (the white-space between the `blockquote` and the `:first-child` pseudo-class:

```
blockquote :first-child {...}
blockquote :last-child {...}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mquv4/1/).

As-written, your selector was selecting the `blockquote` which was itself the `:first-child`, *and* the `blockquote` that was, itself, the `:last-child`, of its parent element.

References:

- [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/).